# CSS - Unwanted margin/padding at top of browser window

Tags: html, css

Please see this url: http://qwiet.com/index.html

Note the 20px or so at the top, above the pagewrap. I want the pagewrap div to be at the top of the browser and extend to the bottom. I've tried inspecting in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari and can't seem to find anything that is adding this margin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some code in your body tag above the conditional comment - see all the dashes:

```
 <body>-----
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
```

Delete those. Then you can give your body a `margin:0` like Mike suggested and you should be set.

Comment: Good find.  I didn't notice that... 
but like AlienWebguy said, a combination of removing that erroneous code and removing the body margin will get you where you want to be.

Comment: wow, thanks. That was it. Cat must have stepped on the keyboard when I wasn't looking :)

Comment: I've heard of cats leaving mice on the doorstep, but leaving bugs in the code - that's taking their evil, morbid generosity to the next level ;)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the default margin from the body tag.  Appending this to your css should do the trick:

```
body { margin: 0px; }
```

Similarly, I'd recommend looking into css resets.  There are some helpful resources on this in the book "Handcrafted CSS" by Dan Cederholm

Comment: Everyone has their own CSS reset of choice. If you poke around SO enough you'll find dozens to choose from.

Comment: I just did this. The gap got a little smaller, but it's still there.

Comment: See AlienWebguy's response for the rest of the fix.  I hadn't thoroughly read your question and thought there was supposed to be some (just not as much) padding above the container.